# In Apache how do I redirect all traffic going to scales.ejiw.com to scales.ejco.com?

Tags: apache, redirect

Our old domain is scales.ejiw.com and our new domain is scales.ejco.com.  For awhile I would like to run both in tandem with scales.ejiw.com just redirecting to scales.ejco.com.  How do I set this up in Apache?  Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the best way to go is with a **301 redirection**.

First of all because its search engine friendly and second of all cause its pretty easy to set up.

The best way to this with Apache is to edit the **.htaccess** file in the document root of your server and add the following lines:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks 
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^newdomain\.com 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

*(Change the newdomain.com with your new domain of-course)*

This way is will redirect 'www' and non 'www' traffic.

You can read some more about 301 redirections [here](http://www.mcanerin.com/EN/articles/301-redirect-apache.asp).